# Debugger output not showing for keyboard in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am making a custom keyboard. The output for the normal part of my app works fine, meaning that I can print things to the console.

Here it is working fine:

[image: Working fine]

However, no debug statements from the custom keyboard target I made for IOS print to the console.

For example, here the print statement should output "Loading view" to the console since the keyboard view is showing on screen but nothing happens:

[image: Problem Case]

I'll provide any relevant Xcode settings if needed.

Why is the output not showing up?

Comment: You can use breakpoints. By build and run, bring up your keyboard, then in Xcode -> Debug ->Attach to Process -> Keyboard

Answer (score 2):

In case this is still unsolved:

The keyboard runs in a different process than the main app. The debugger attaches to a single process only. In order to attach the debugger to the keyboard, create a new Scheme in Xcode (The stuff to the right of the run/stop buttons) with your keyboard extension as target and run this one instead of the main app scheme.